# Grab element data attr with .children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap carousel, and I need to display a div based on which slide is currently visible.
I am thinking that I can grab the `data-slide-to` attribute value and use that to display a div with a matching `data-carousel-slide` value.
I am having trouble getting the `data-slide-to value`. Below is what I have so far.

HTML

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
</ol>
```

The above links allow us to move to specific slides - you can check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)
for more detail on the carousel. Further down, I have created some `div`s that contain text that I want to display.

HTML 2

```
<div class="carousel-slide-main-data" id="data-0" data-carousel-slide="0">
    <h4>Slide Number One</h4>
    <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.
        Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="carousel-slide-main-data" id="data-1" data-carousel-slide="1">
    <h4>Slide Number Two</h4>
    <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.
        Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.
    </p>
</div>
```

Finally, this is the JS that I'm trying to use

```
function openData() {
    var slide_to = $('.carousel-indicators').children();
    console.log(slide_to);
}

$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: false });
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', openData);
```

I can't seem to target the correct `li` tag, and therefore can't get the data-slide-to value - any help would be awesome.

Comment: You are not using the proper selectors, here an example for it:https://jsfiddle.net/thnn5955/1/, but you well understand that in this way you are only getting only the first one. Please describe what you want to do.

Comment: @allicarn That's not necessarily a typo as there are both 'slide.bs.carousel' and 'slid.bs.carousel' events.

Comment: @GeorgeSecrieru you're totally right; I didn't realize that.

Comment: @franco In a nutshell I need to get the currently active li and the data-slide-to number. Once i have that I need to update the css on the div with the ID that matches the number. I have made an update to the openData function       `function openData() {
        var slide_to = $('.carousel-indicators li').attr("class");
        if(slide_to == "active") {
          alert($('.carousel-indicators li').data('slide-to'));
        }
        console.log(slide_to);
      }`     -however this only runs once, instead of on every slide change

Comment: @virtualLast Try changing your selector to `$('.carousel-indicators li.active').eq(0).data('slide-to')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of what is the current active slide if you track the Event object that is (supposed to be) passed to your handler:

```
function openData(e) {
    // this is the visible slide - i.e. probably a .carousel-inner .item element
    console.log($(e.relatedTarget));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @gmsecrieru, you can get data about the slid event, including the slide that was newly made active.  You can then get the index of that slide, and find the related element using the [attribute equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector.

Note that this depends on the data attribute not changing in JS (the markup that we are using to select the element will not change from on load).

See below for a working example.

```js
function openData(e) {
    var slide_to = 0;
    if(e) {
      slide_to = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    }
    $('.carousel-slide-main-data').hide();
    $('.carousel-slide-main-data').filter("[data-carousel-slide='"+slide_to+"']").show();
}

$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: false });
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', openData);

openData();
```

```css
.carousel-slide-main-data {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/?1" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        First Carousel Item
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400?2" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Second Carousel Item
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400?3" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Third Carousel Item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-slide-main-data" id="data-0" data-carousel-slide="0">
    <h4>Slide Number One</h4>
    <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.
        Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="carousel-slide-main-data" id="data-1" data-carousel-slide="1">
    <h4>Slide Number Two</h4>
    <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.
        Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I get the `whichSlideIndex`? var slide_to should equal the currently active slide - each time the slideshow 'slides' the active class changes

Comment: I have updated my answer; I misunderstood what you were asking, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

In case people are interested I managed to achieve what I wanted with the below code.

```
function qs(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
    var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
    var slide = match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    if (Math.floor(slide) == slide && $.isNumeric(slide))
        return parseInt(slide);
    else
        return 0;
  } //end qs
  function displayData(key) {
    $('#data-' + key).css('display', 'block');
  }// end displayData
  function openData() {
    var slide_to = $('.carousel-indicators li.active').eq(0).data('slide-to');
    var carousel_data = $('.carousel-slide-main-data').children();
    carousel_data.css('display', 'none');
    displayData(slide_to);
  }

  $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: false});
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(qs('slide'));
  displayData(qs('slide'));
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', openData);
```

So the above code checks to see which slide we should start on when the page loads (according to get variable in URL) , we then display a div which matches the slide, then when a new slide comes in we get the slide-to value and pass that to displayData, but just before that we close any currently displaying content div's - it may not be the best but at least it's working, if anyone can improve upon it please let me know - have a good one.